Как сделать кнопки в одном ряду, а не столбиком
Не пойму как сделать кнопки не столбиком, и как удалять предыдущие сообщения бота telebot
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def sbot(message):
  first_mess = f"<b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>, Привет!\nНажмите нужный вам вопрос?"
  markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
  button_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Меню', callback_data='Кнопка')
  markup.add(button_yes)
  button_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='no')
  markup.add(button_no)
  button_maybe = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Возможно', callback_data='maybe')
  markup.add(button_maybe)
  bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id - 1)
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, first_mess, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def response(function_call):
  if function_call.message:
     if function_call.data == "Кнопка":
        second_mess = "Выберете ваш вопрос"
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка1", callback_data='yes'))
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка2", callback_data='no'))
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Кнопка3", callback_data='no'))
        bot.send_message(function_call.message.chat.id, second_mess, reply_markup=markup)
        bot.answer_callback_query(function_call.id)
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(function_call.message.chat.id, message_id=function_call.message.message_id,
                                      reply_markup=None)


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать отдельными вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

b1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Библиотека', callback_data='bibl')
b2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Анализ данных', callback_data='data')
b3 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='списки', callback_data='list')
row1 = [ b1, b2 ]
row2 = [ b3 ]
buttons = [ row1, row2 ]
markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons)`введите `введите сюда код`сюда код


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
